# QGis Plugin Trouble with QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins, pyqt4, qgis

Im currently working on a QGis Plugin (I create a example using Plugin Builder), this plugin should show Features of selected VectorLayers in a QTableWidget. I have two files cactus.py (main program) and UI_cactus_dialog_base.py (Ui file designed on QtCreator).
The trouble is: from main program I can't setItems on QTableWidget and I don't know why (, I'm very new on QGis/Python programming and I'm very confused with self/iface/ui instances. Help please!

`cactus.py`

```
class Cactus:
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
    self.tablewidget = QTableWidget()
    # initialize plugin directory
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # initialize locale
    locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    locale_path = os.path.join(
        self.plugin_dir,
        'i18n',
        'Cactus_{}.qm'.format(locale))

    if os.path.exists(locale_path):
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(locale_path)

        if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
    self.dlg = Ui_cactus_dialog_base()
    self.dlg.show_record = self.show_record
    self.dlg.eje_tablewidget = self.tablewidget
    # Declare instance attributes
    self.actions = []
    self.menu = self.tr(u'&Cactus')
    # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Cactus')
    self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'Cactus')

# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
def tr(self, message):

    return QCoreApplication.translate('Cactus', message)


def add_action(
    self,
    icon_path,
    text,
    callback,
    enabled_flag=True,
    add_to_menu=True,
    add_to_toolbar=True,
    status_tip=None,
    whats_this=None,
    parent=None):


    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

    if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)

    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)

    return action

def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/Cactus/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Cactus - Creacion manzanas a partir de ejes'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Cactus'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar


def run(self):

    self.dlg.setupUi(self.dlg)

    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass


@pyqtSlot()
def show_record(self):
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()   
    ejes = layer.selectedFeatures()
    print len(ejes)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for eje in ejes:
        i = i + 1
        for column in eje:
            item = QTableWidgetItem('ejee_id')
            self.tablewidget.setItem(i, j, item)
            print item
            j = j + 1
```

`UI_cactus_dialog_base.py`

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
def _fromUtf8(s):
    return s

try:
  _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_cactus_dialog_base(QtGui.QDialog):
  def setupUi(self, cactus_dialog_base):
    cactus_dialog_base.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cactus_dialog_base"))
    cactus_dialog_base.resize(567, 504)
    self.buffer = QtGui.QPushButton(cactus_dialog_base)
    self.buffer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 440, 262, 41))
    self.buffer.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buffer"))
    self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(cactus_dialog_base)
    self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 541, 61))
    self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.lbl_capa = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
    self.lbl_capa.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lbl_capa"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lbl_capa, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.layer_name = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
    self.layer_name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layer_name"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.layer_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.lbl_geometria = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
    self.lbl_geometria.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lbl_geometria"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lbl_geometria, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.geometry_type = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
    self.geometry_type.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("geometry_type"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.geometry_type, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(cactus_dialog_base)
    self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 541, 201))
    self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
    self.eje_tablewidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.groupBox)
    self.eje_tablewidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 521, 171))
    self.eje_tablewidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("eje_tablewidget"))
    self.eje_tablewidget.setColumnCount(18)
    self.eje_tablewidget.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(10, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(11, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(12, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(13, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(14, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(15, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(16, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.eje_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(17, item)

    self.retranslateUi(cactus_dialog_base)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buffer, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), cactus_dialog_base.show_record)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cactus_dialog_base)

def retranslateUi(self, cactus_dialog_base):
    cactus_dialog_base.setWindowTitle(_translate("cactus_dialog_base",           "Cactus", None))
    self.buffer.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Asignar Buffer", None))
    self.lbl_capa.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Capa Actual:", None))
    self.layer_name.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Layer_Name", None))
    self.lbl_geometria.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Tipo Geometría:", None))
    self.geometry_type.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Geometry_Type", None))
    self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "Ejes Seleccionados", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_id", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_tipo", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_nombre", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_nombre_completo", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_izq_inicio", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_izq_termino", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_der_inicio", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_der_termino", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_clase_funcional", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_categoria_velocidad", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(10)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_doble_sentido", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(11)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_transito_automovil", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(12)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_transito_bus", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(13)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_pavimentado", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(14)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_pago", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(15)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_link_id", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(16)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_geom", None))
    item = self.eje_tablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(17)
    item.setText(_translate("cactus_dialog_base", "ejee_explica", None))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. At the current code there is one thing missing.

The QtableWidget needs to be told when to add rows with the `setRowCount()` method.

So actually you need to add one row before you use it. And the same goes for the columns.

And before you start the "for loop" you are having, you need to `setRowCount()` to zero in order to "erase the data from the table" cause that's how the QTableWidget works.

You could also make it more dynamic by using the rowCount and the columnCount of the table or use the `eje.attribute["column_name"]` to get the specific column you want to add in a standard column position. For example you already know that the

```
eje.attribue["user_name"]
```

is the 3rd column, so you don't need nested loop for the columns, instead, you can ->

```
self.tablewidget.setItem(QTableWidgetItem(self.tablewidget.rowCount()-1,3,eje.attribute["user_name"]))
```